# In the following code variable 'checkNumber' is not incrementing to 1 even after 'if' block get executed and so that Break is not working

Tags: cypress

In the following code variable 'checkNumber' is not incrementing to 1 even after 'if' block get executed and so that Break is not working where i need to break the loop

```
var checkNumber =0
for (let i = 0; i < totalRowCountAllocPrj; i++){
    allocationObjects.getAllocationStatusfromGrid(i).then(text => {      
        appAllocStatus = Cypress.$(text).text()
        cy.log("Allocation Status :" + appAllocStatus)
        if(appAllocStatus == userData.approvalReservedAllocStatus){
            allocationObjects.getAppAllCheckBoxesfromGrid(i).click()
            checkNumber=checkNumber+1
            cy.log("index="+i)
        }
        else{
            cy.log("Project is not Reserved")
        }
        
    })
    cy.log("number="+checkNumber)
    if(checkNumber==1)
    {
        break
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `checkNumber` gets incremented inside an asynchronous command, but the loop is running synchronously.

You can't use `break` but you should be able to stop executing the commands with the inverse check.

Since `checkNumber` never should go above 0, it's more sensible to use a boolean

```js
let found = 0

for (let i = 0; i < totalRowCountAllocPrj; i++) {

  cy.then(() => {

    if (!found) {
      allocationObjects.getAllocationStatusfromGrid(i).then(text => {
        appAllocStatus = Cypress.$(text).text()
        if (appAllocStatus === userData.approvalReservedAllocStatus) {
          allocationObjects.getAppAllCheckBoxesfromGrid(i).click()
          found = true
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

**BTW** you should be able to rewrite `allocationObjects.getAllocationStatusfromGrid()` to directly search for `userData.approvalReservedAllocStatus` and get rid of the loop altogether.